# Adding setter to readonly computed var using public extension in a Swift framework

Tags: ios, swift

### Problem

I'd like to write reusable extensions for standard classes and put them in a shared Swift framework. Some of these extensions provide a setter for a readonly computed variable of the class they extend by overwriting the computed variable with an own one.

This works fine as long as the extension is part of the app project itself (where the extension is actually used). When I move the extension to a framework and `import` it, then using the extension's variable fails with error `ambiguous use of 'propertyName'` at the call site. I.e. Swift doesn't know whether to call the original implementation or the one of the imported module.

### Example: CGRect

```
import CoreGraphics


public extension CGRect {

    public var width: CGFloat {
        get { return size.width }  // using this causes ambiguous call error
        mutating set { size.width = newValue }  // what I actually want to add
    }
}
```

This works fine unless I move the code to a framework and import this framework.

### Question

Now my question is wether I can either

- tell Swift which module's version of the property should be used or
- tell Swift that my module always overwrites the original property or
- add a setter without implementing a new getter which would resolve the ambiguous call.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  When I removed public everything was fine.